# Root element is missing when transforming a simple config with Remove

Tags: xml, octopus-deploy, config-transformation

I have a simple xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<rootElement>
 ...
</rootElement>
```

And I am transforming it with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<rootElement xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xdt:Transform="Remove">
 ...
</rootElement>
```

And then I get this exception during build:

```
Exception while replacing configuration-variables in: D:\...\rootelement.config
17:52:12Error
System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
17:52:12Error
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
17:52:12Error
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)
17:52:12Error
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
17:52:12Error
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
17:52:12Error
   at Calamari.Integration.ConfigurationVariables.ConfigurationVariablesReplacer.ReadXmlDocument(String configurationFilePath) in Y:\work\14ffc968155e4956\source\Calamari\Integration\ConfigurationVariables\ConfigurationVariablesReplacer.cs:line 62
```

Note, I have about 10 other similar config files that are transforming without problems but this is the only one that does "Remove" instead of "Replace" so I suspect that might be an issue.

Also when I preview the transformation locally it works fine, so maybe it's an issue with Octopus deploy and that "Calamari" library

Comment: What exactly do you need? Do you want to have a final XML file that is completely empty? In which case you can leave your original config as empty, and the transformation empty as well. 

If all other transformations do dumb replace, then I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Although your problem seems like bug in calamari.

Comment: I have my reasons to have this structure and my problem is that "previewing" works fine and transforming it with a build task works fine but Calamari crashes. Seems like a bug with Calamari

Comment: I raised a bug request with the Octopus team:
https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/2513

Answer (score 2):

XML documents require a root element, so the transformation results in a invalid XML document.

This error happens after the transformation, when Octopus tries to replace variables in the file.  The XML document is invalid, so it cannot be loaded.

The transformation needs to be changed so that it results in a valid XML document.